# Cockpit UI is unresponsive and cockpit-bridge consumes high CPU

Tags: server, cockpit

I can't get Cockpit version 260 to work on Unbuntu Server 21.10.  The web ui is unresponsive: most actions do nothing; switching to another tab shows a blank window or a spinning wheel.  On the console, I can see that cockpit-bridge is consuming high CPU:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  17993 stacy     20   0  628308 285128   7708 R  84.1   3.5   0:33.87 cockpit-bridge
    654 root      20   0  396232  13428  10596 S  18.9   0.2   0:17.86 udisksd
    395 root      20   0   24964   6428   3612 R  15.9   0.1   0:19.93 systemd-udevd
    637 message+  20   0    9432   5744   4272 S  11.6   0.1   0:09.53 dbus-daemon
      1 root      20   0   98976  10964   7812 S   2.7   0.1   0:06.90 systemd
```

If I logout of the web UI (one of the few things that seems to work), and log back in, I can see multiple version of cockpit-bridge spinning:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  53008 stacy     20   0  582196 335300   7636 R  32.1   4.2   0:23.02 cockpit-bridge
  17993 stacy     20   0 1736296   1.3g   7708 R  30.1  16.4   2:16.33 cockpit-bridge
    637 message+  20   0   11280   7784   4272 R  29.8   0.1   0:33.98 dbus-daemon
  60857 stacy     20   0  333724  91716   7584 R  27.5   1.1   0:03.58 cockpit-bridge
    654 root      20   0  396328  13448  10596 R  17.2   0.2   0:43.72 udisksd
    395 root      20   0   24964   6428   3612 S  15.2   0.1   0:45.82 systemd-udevd
    653 root      20   0   46452   7200   6352 S   3.0   0.1   0:06.31 systemd-logind
      1 root      20   0   98976  10968   7812 S   2.6   0.1   0:11.49 systemd
```

I started out with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, and Cockpit installed from the default repo.  As that didn't work I installed the backport versions, and upgraded to Unbuntu Server 21.10.

Besides that I've tried uninstall/reinstall multiple times/ways, e.g.:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove cockpit*

. /etc/os-release
sudo apt install -t ${VERSION_CODENAME}-backports cockpit
```

I've also tried removing a few individual cockpit related packages, and switching from networkd to NetworkManager.

That's the extent of my skills/google fu.

Help!